# Adapting binary stacking example to multiclass

Tags: python, matrix, machine-learning, ensemble-learning

I have been studying [this example of stacking](https://github.com/emanuele/kaggle_pbr/blob/master/blend.py). In this case, each set of K-folds produces one column of data, and this is repeated for each classifier. I.e: the matrices for blending are:

```
dataset_blend_train = np.zeros((X.shape[0], len(clfs)))
dataset_blend_test = np.zeros((X_submission.shape[0], len(clfs)))
```

I need to stack predictions from a multiclass problem (probs 15 different classes per sample). This will produce an n*15 matrix for each clf.

Should these matrices just be concatenated horizontally? Or should they be combined in some other way, before logistic regression is applied? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can adapt the code to the multi-class problem in two ways:

1. Concatenate horizontally the probabilities, that is you will need to create:
   `dataset_blend_train = np.zeros((X.shape[0], len(clfs)*numOfClasses))`
   `dataset_blend_test = np.zeros((X_submission.shape[0], len(clfs)*numOfClasses))`
2. Instead of using probabilities, use the class prediction for the base models. That way you keep the arrays the same size, but instead of `predict_proba` you just use `predict`.

I have used both successfully, but which works better may depend on the dataset.

Answer (score 0):

There is also the problem of extending the features as you cycle through each classifier. I use the following:

```
db_train = np.zeros((X_train.shape[0], np.unique(y).shape[0]))    
db_test = clf.predict_proba(X_test)   

...

try:
    dataset_blend_train
except NameError:
    dataset_blend_train = db_train
else:
    dataset_blend_train = np.hstack((dataset_blend_train, db_train))

try:
    dataset_blend_test
except NameError:
    dataset_blend_test = db_test
else:
    dataset_blend_test = np.hstack((dataset_blend_test, db_test))
```